# Ruby - Changing Information Data Structure - Array/Hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash, highcharts

I'm attempting to convert data contained in a pair of data structures to a format that is compatible with HighCharts (A JS Chart Library). The initial data structure is filled by parsing a JSON file. (I cannot alter this step, and must instead work with the resulting data structure) The initial data structures look like this:

**Initialization:**

```
@areaBreakdown = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new } 
@deptBreakdown = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = Hash.new }
```

**Sample Data @areaBreakdown:**

```
{#<Area id: 1, area_code: "123", created_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11",
updated_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11", name: "testarea1",
org_code: "123456">=>{"areaScore"=>46.65},
#<Area id: 2, area_code: "456", created_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11",
updated_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11", name: "testarea2",
org_code: "123456">=>{"areaScore"=>52.98}}
```

**Sample Data @deptBreakdown:**

```
{#<Dept id: 1, dept_code: "78910", created_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11",
updated_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11", name: "testdeptunderarea1",
area_id: 1>=>{"deptScore"=>46.65},
#<Dept id: 2, dept_code: "4567", created_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11",
updated_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11", name: "testdept1underarea2",
area_id: 2>=>{"deptScore"=>49.81},
#<Dept id: 3, dept_code: "99999", created_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11",
updated_at: "2014-04-04 20:23:11", name: "testdept2underarea2",
area_id: 2>=>{"deptScore"=>56.15}}
```

Highchart takes two separate data structures for the chart I am trying to build. 
*areaBreakdown* has to be converted to an array of hashes, with each index corresponding to a different area. Array name is *areaScores*.

**Hardcoded Version of areaScores:**

```
@hardCodedAreaScores = Array.new
# Push a Hash onto the array
@hardCodedAreaScores.push Hash.new
# Access the newly pushed hash by giving it a key, value pair to add
@hardCodedAreaScores[0]["name"] = "area1"
# Do it again
@hardCodedAreaScores[0]["drilldown"] = "area1"
# And again
@hardCodedAreaScores[0]["y"] = 35.15

@hardCodedAreaScores.push Hash.new
@hardCodedAreaScores[1]["name"] = "area2"
@hardCodedAreaScores[1]["drilldown"] = "area2"
@hardCodedAreaScores[1]["y"] = 45.59
```

The conversion of *@deptBreakdown*, *deptScores* should be an array of hashes. Each hash should have 3 keys: "name", "id", and "data". "name" = "id" = "drilldown". Data is an array of arrays that holds the data point for the chart to display. Example, "data" = [ [x1, y1], [x2, y2] ].

**Hardcoded Example of deptScores:**

```
@hardCodedDepartmentScores = Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores.push Hash.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["name"] = "area1"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["id"] = "area1"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"] = Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"][0] = Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"][0].push "Department1UnderArea1"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"][0].push 20.15
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"].push Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"][1].push "Department2UnderArea1"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[0]["data"][1].push 69.69
@hardCodedDepartmentScores.push Hash.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["name"] = "area2"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["id"] = "area2"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"] = Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"][0] = Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"][0].push "Department1UnderArea2"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"][0].push 98.21
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"].push Array.new
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"][1].push "Department2UnderArea2"
@hardCodedDepartmentScores[1]["data"][1].push 12.34
```

**My Attempt:**

```
def cycleThroughProcessedDataAndCreateHighChartsDataSetsBreakdown(areaBreakdown, deptBreakdown, employBreakdown)
areaScores = Array.new
areaScores.push Hash.new
deptScores = Array.new
deptScores.push Hash.new
counter = 0
deptCounter = 0
areaCounter = 0

  areaBreakdown.each_key do |area|
   areaScores.push Hash.new
   areaScores[counter]["name"] = areaBreakdown[area]["name"]
   areaScores[counter]["drilldown"] = areaBreakdown[area]["name"]
   areaScores[counter]["areaScore"] = areaBreakdown[area]["areaScore"]

   deptScores.push Hash.new
   deptScores[areaCounter]["name"] = areaBreakdown[area]["name"]
   deptScores[areaCounter]["id"] = areaBreakdown[area]["name"]


   deptBreakdown.each_key do |dept|
    if deptScores[counter]["area_id"] == areaBreakdown[area]["area_id"]
      deptScores[counter]["data"] = Array.new
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter] = Array.new
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter].push deptBreakdown[dept]["name"]
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter].push deptBreakdown[dept]["deptScore"]

      deptCounter += 1
    end     
  #areaCounter += 1
  end
counter += 1
end
debugger

return deptScores, areaScores
end
```

My question is how to properly convert the two initial data structures (or the two hardcoded versions) to the needed data structures. I am somewhat new to ruby and I am having trouble accessing certain information like name and id. I am also running into a number of null method errors when trying to iterate and fill out the various data structures. Iteration must occur because the sizes of *@areaBreakdown* and *@deptBreakdown* are dynamic. How do I properly fill the two data structures *@areaScores* and *@deptScores*?

Thanks,
Matt

P.S. I apologize for the long post. Any help is appreciated. If question is unclear further details will be provided.

**Current Output:**

```
(rdb:1) areaScores
[{"name"=>nil, "drilldown"=>nil, "areaScore"=>46.65}, {"name"=>nil, "drilldown"=>nil, "areaScore"=>52.98}]

(rdb:1) deptScores
[{"name"=>nil, "id"=>nil, "data"=>[nil, nil, [nil, 56.15]]}, {"data"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, [nil, 56.15]]}, {}]
```

Comment: Are you sure that `@areaBreakdown` and `@deptBreakdown` are hashes? They look more like arrays of objects based on that visualisation. Also, could you post the error/errors that you're getting?

Comment: @Doydle That's how they are being initialized aren't they (as hashes)? Currently there aren't any errors, but the output is incomplete and incorrect. I have updated my attempt and have included the current output of both areaScores and deptScores. The output is included at the bottom of the question. I'm still unsure why "name" is coming out as 'nil' in areaScores. The data structure for deptScores is also still off, and similar to areaScores, fields like "name" and "id" are not being filled in. Is there more information I can provide you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to figure out my problem. I wasn't accessing the hash properly when setting names and id. I have included my solution below:

**Solution:**

```
areaScores = Array.new  
deptScores = Array.new
counter = 0

areaBreakdown.each_key do |area|
  deptCounter = 0
  areaScores.push Hash.new
  areaScores[counter]["name"] = area["name"]
  areaScores[counter]["drilldown"] = area["name"]
  areaScores[counter]["y"] = areaBreakdown[area]["areaScore"]

  deptScores.push Hash.new
  deptScores[counter]["name"] = area["name"]
  deptScores[counter]["id"] = area["name"]
  deptScores[counter]["data"] = Array.new

  deptBreakdown.each_key do |dept|
    if dept["area_id"] == area["id"] #if department belongs to area 
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter] = Array.new
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter].push dept["name"]
      deptScores[counter]["data"][deptCounter].push deptBreakdown[dept]["deptScore"]
      deptCounter += 1
    end #if     
  end #deptBreakdown
  counter += 1
end #areaBreakdown
#debugger
return deptScores, areaScores
```

Thanks for the help!